How to get the count of total rows from ag-grid with serveur side row model (datasource) using vue js?
I'm using ag-grid and vue, with the server side row model.
I would like to display the count of all the rows, and not only the displayed rows but really the count of all the rows from database. This value (rowCount: response.data.lastRow) is available in createServerSideDatasource(), but this function is outside my component so I can't access to this value in data() section. And I would like to do something like that : this.totalRows = response.data.lastRow (cf. extract of code below).
I already try to add cont vm = this in the createServerSideDatasource() function, but I doesn't fix my problem because vm.totalRows is still unreachable in the data() section.
So here are my question :

How can I make value from an outside function (here response.data.lastRow value) reachable in the data() section ?

<template>
    <p>{{ totalRows }}</p>
    <ag-grid
        rowModelType="serverSide"
        ...
    >
    </ag-grid>
</template>

<script>
import { AgGridVue } from 'ag-grid-vue3'
import 'ag-grid-enterprise'
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css'

export default {
    name: 'list',
    components: {
        AgGridVue
    },  
    data() {
        return {
            gridApi: null,
            totalRows: 0, //==>get the value from createServerSideDatasource()
        }
    },
    
    methods() {
        onGridReady(params) {
            this.gridApi = params.api
            this.gridApi.setGridOption("serverSideDatasource", createServerSideDatasource())
        }
    },
}

function createServerSideDatasource() {
  return {
    getRows: function(params) {
      let sortColumn = null
      let sortDirection = null
      if (params.request.sortModel.length > 0) {
        sortColumn = params.request.sortModel[0].colId
        sortDirection = params.request.sortModel[0].sort
      }

      User.list(params.request.startRow, params.request.endRow, sortColumn, sortDirection, window.searchText).then((response) => {
        if (response.data.success) {
        
          params.success({
            rowData: response.data.rows,
            rowCount: response.data.lastRow,
          })

          //==>make something like that : this.totalRows = response.data.lastRow
          
        }
        else {
          params.fail()
        }
      })
    },
  }
}
</script>


This question cannot be Vue3 and 2 at the same time. As for the question itself, can't you access the value with template refs?

@kissu yes I tried to access it with refs but without success.

As you are using the Enterprise version, you have the Status Bar.
Within the Status Bar, you must use the following property:
{ statusPanel: 'agTotalRowCountComponent' },   

On this page of the documentation, there is also a section on server-side information.
Regarding your question, try referencing the vue instance inside the function:
function createServerSideDatasource(vm) { // Receives the component reference
  return {
    getRows: function(params) {
      let sortColumn = null
      let sortDirection = null
      if (params.request.sortModel.length > 0) {
        sortColumn = params.request.sortModel[0].colId
        sortDirection = params.request.sortModel[0].sort
      }

      User.list(params.request.startRow, params.request.endRow, sortColumn, sortDirection, window.searchText).then((response) => {
        if (response.data.success) {
          params.success({
            rowData: response.data.rows,
            rowCount: response.data.lastRow,
          })

          vm.totalRows = response.data.lastRow; // Updates the totalRows property

        } else {
          params.fail()
        }
      })
    },
  }
}

